# Transfer photos and videos from another person's iCloud shared photo album to my own iCloud photo album

Tags: photos, photo-sharing, album, icloud

I got a link to a shared iCloud photo album that looks like this:

```
https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0xG6XBvbrxqU5g
```

I just learned that *it is not possible* to transfer this album, or a subset of the images and videos in this album, to one of my own albums on iCloud -- other than to *download every single image and video* one at a time and then to *upload everything again*, to my own iCloud.

Can it be true? Is there no better way to access images except to downloading them one at a time?

Answer (score 3):

They can invite you (by email) to their shared album, and it will be accessible from your iCloud Account.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that this is not possible unless you are invited personally and not only have a sharing link like the one mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.